# How to get login in laravel 5 app using $.ajax()

Tags: ajax, laravel, single-sign-on

I have a **laravel 5** app. In the app, **login functionality is developed with angularjs** (requesting email/password with $http()). Now there is another .net app. I want to let **.net user to request (by sending email/password using jquery ajax)** to get logged in into my system. Response will be JSON. If response will be success, .net app system will redirect page into laravel 5 app. I have **requested to login using $.ajax()**. But problem is that laravel 5 throws **TokenMismatchException** error. So I need to **pass csrf token**. But I don't know that **how I can pass csrf token in ajax request from .net app to laravel 5 app**. If anyone knows the solution, it will be appreciated. And also if there is any alternative standard approach for .net to laravel 5 login, it will be also appreciated.

**laravel 5 - Angular login**

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: LOGIN_CONTROLLER_URL,
    data: {
        st_email: 'some@email.com',
        st_password: 'dowhateveryouwanttodo'
        }
    });
```

**JQuery Ajax login**

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: LOGIN_CONTROLLER_URL,
    data: {
        st_email: 'some@email.com',
        st_password: 'dowhateveryouwanttodo'
        }
    });
```

Comment: i think the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token) has the info you need.

Comment: @CerlinBoss, Yes, laravel has documentaion on this. But I want to implement this on .net app. So `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` is not option for me. because `csrf-token()` is laravel function. Is there any alternate function in .net?

Comment: You have permission to edit laravel code?

Comment: @CerlinBoss, `You have permission to edit laravel code?` Means?

Comment: i mean, do you own/maintain the laravel code

Comment: @CerlinBoss, Yes, I'm maintaining laravel code.

Comment: then you should disable csrf verification middleware for the route for which you are sending ajax request.

Comment: @CerlinBoss, Can you explain with code example? Beacause I have confusion that if I disables csrf verification, then will laravel will work same for other modules. And one more thing that I want this functionality (.net to laravel 5) only for login. After success response, .net app will open laravel 5 app in new tab.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122797/discussion-between-cerlin-boss-and-akshay-vaghasiya).

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you the [JWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token) (JSON Web Token). CSRF token only protects you from attacks. To login use `JWT`. There are many packages/bundles on web that you can use in your project. For Laravel one of the best is:

[JSON Web Token Authentication for Laravel & Lumen](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth)

Comment: one downside of JWT is, you cannot invalidate a token from server side. The max you can do is blacklisting it.