# How I can modify response (JSON instead of redirection) if user is already logged in in laravel 5.2?

Tags: laravel, single-sign-on, laravel-authorization

First look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39361323/how-to-get-login-in-laravel-5-app-using-ajax). I have solved that problem by getting **XSRF-TOKEN token from request cookie**.

**VerifyCsrfToken.php**

```
$token = $request->input('_token') ? : $request->header('X-CSRF-TOKEN');
// By Me - Start
if($token == null) {
    $token = $request->cookie('XSRF-TOKEN');
}
// By Me - End
```

This works fine. But my problem is that if user is get logged in once, then on requesting again from .net app, I'm **getting html(view) response**. I **want to update that response as JSON response**. I have tried to debug. But I can't find any function from where I can modify that response. If any one knows the solution or alternative way, it will be appreciated.

Comment: Show us the method in your controller. Probably you first should check if it is an ajax call and return `html` or `json`.  Use `$request->ajax()` to check.

Comment: @ThomasVanderVeen, I'm making request from $.ajax() from .net app. So it is calling `login() of AuthController`. But on debugging, I'm getting response before that function is called.